# Is it fine to use static array as a fixed database to display a list of words?

Tags: android

I'm working on an app for Android that display a list of words..I don't want user to modify the list.
So is it fine to use static array as a fixed database to display a list of words (about 500 words)?
should I use SQLite database ?...what is the advantage ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you aren't modifying the array of words (its a constant) a static variable should be fine for you.

However, if you're simply storing words I would suggest using `SharedPreferences`.

Otherwise, if you have bigger plans for this `SQLite` may be the best way for you to go. The advantage of `SQLite` is that it will offer a managed and robust way to store and access your data, and its very reliant. Moreover, if you ever wanted to grow your number of words (to hundreds of thousands, say) then `SQLite` could handle this without a problem.

Comment: Thanks!...sorry I was thinking in many ways
your answer is helpful...thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Using an array seems perfectly fine for what you are doing, using an on-phone SQLite database seems overkill to me. The only reason I could see doing it would be for extensibility later on, if you plan on adding additional functionality later on then the SQLite db may be the way to go(or even abstract it away with a ContentProvider, for even more extensibility, but yet again probably overkill for your needs).